# how to remove header, transpose the data and combine 100 files into a new csv file?

Tags: python, file, csv

I have 900 files and all the files are in one folder. 
The files name are like `"0_dcef_abcd_cdef"`, `"1_dcef_cdef_abcd"` and inside the files the columns look like: 
File 1:

```
col1   col2       
1      2    
3      4
```

File 2:

```
col1    col2

5       6

7       8
```

I want to create a new csv file where the headers will be removed from the previous files and the data are transposed and in the new csv file the columns will look like:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 

0    dcef abcd cdef 1,3  2,4 

1    dcef cdef abcd 5,7  6,8
```

I have tried like this:

```
import os

path = 'c:\\path'
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        print (file)
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            data = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter=',', encoding='latin-1') 

            st = file[0]
            st1 = file[2:6]
            st2 = file[7:11]
            st3 = file[12:16]
            print (st,st1,st2,st3)

            #  perform calculation
            with open('c:\\path\filename.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:    # saving into the csv file
                saes = csv.writer(csvfile)
                saes.writerow(['col1']+["col2"]+["col3"]+["col4"]+ ['col5']+["col6"])
                saes.writerow([st]+ [st1]+[st2]+[st3]+ +data["col1"]+data["col2"])
```

but it is not working. I don't know how to transpose the columns. or change other columns to hex to decimal and save it to the new csv.

can anyone help me to do this code please?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: not enough information. what have you tried? post code. cannot see how to get from files 1 and 2 to your desired output.

Comment: I have posted the code. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I think this approach might help:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

csv_files = glob.glob('*.csv') # get a list of all csv files in the current folder
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6']) 
counter = 0

for csv_file in csv_files:
    df_file = pd.read_csv(csv_file,delimiter=',',encoding='latin-1')
    file_name_parts = csv_file.split('.')[0]
    file_name_parts = file_name_parts.split('_')  
    columns_list = []
    for column in df_file.columns:  # transform all columns into a list of comma separated strings 
        columns_list.append(df_file.loc[:,column].to_csv(header=None, index=False).strip('\n').replace('\n',','))    
    df.loc[counter] = file_name_parts + columns_list  # add the new row to the dataframe
    counter += 1
df.to_csv(r'C:\path\filename.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: yeah it works. I have another question:
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 

0    dcef abcd cdef 1,3  2,4 

1    dcef cdef abcd 5,7  6,8
I want to change the col2, col3, col4 from hex to decimal. How can I do that?